# Setup a Mercurial Webserver on OSX

Tags: macos, apache, mercurial, webserver, cgi

I am trying to setup a Mercurial web server on OSX.
and I have followed this procedure: http://devravenio.blogspot.be/2013/02/set-up-mercurial-server-on-mac-os-x.html

So I have created a /var/hg folder inside which I have these files:

- MyRepo
- hgusers
- hgweb.config
- hgweb.cgi
- httpd-hg.conf

When I run the webserver like this:

```
https://localhost/hg/MyRepo
```

I get this error

```
[error] [client 10.0.27.146] client denied by server configuration: /var/hg/hgweb.cgi
```

Here is the content of hgweb.cgi

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# send python tracebacks to the browser if an error occurs:
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

# An example CGI script to export multiple hgweb repos, edit as necessary
# adjust python path if not a system-wide install:
import sys
#input mercurial path
sys.path.insert(0, "/Library/python/2.7/site-packages/mercurial")
# enable importing on demand to reduce startup time
from mercurial import demandimport; demandimport.enable()
from mercurial.hgweb.hgwebdir_mod import hgwebdir
import mercurial.hgweb.wsgicgi as wsgicgi
application = hgwebdir('hgweb.config')
wsgicgi.launch(application)
```

And here is my hgweb.config

```
#hgweb.config

[paths]
MyRepo = /var/hg/MyRepo

[web]
#visiting the given URL paths or including subrepositories
descend = True
allow_push = *
push_ssl = true
#for http://example.com/hg
baseurl = /hg
#for http://hg.example.com
#baseurl =
```

I also put these rights:

```
chown -R _www:_www /var/hg
chmod -R g+rw /var/hg
chmod -R g+x /var/hg
chmod -R g+x /var/hg/*
chmod -R g+x /var/hg/*/.hg
```

Can somebody help my with this problem?

Comment: This is probably better done over on server fault or interactively in the Mercurial IRC channel.  You've got some small misconfiguration, likely in apache not mercurial, but it's off topic for stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanx for your answer Ry4an. I'm gonna have a look at Mercurial IRC so!